Had there ever been an accident caused by chatting in the cockpit?
Almost all large commercial jet airliners today have at least a captain and a first officer as the flight crew. Some cargo aircraft or old airliners also have a flight engineer. Additionally, most long hauled flights have an additional relief captain or even a complete relief flight crew. According to aircraft regulations, pilots should focus on their work and not small talk when in crucial stages of the flight, i.e. taxing, take-off, climb, decent, approach, and landing. In the cruise phase, especially if the flight is a long-haul, the autopilot basically flies the plane on the intended route, and pilots are allowed to chat a little while still monitoring the flight of the aircraft and reacting to any anomalies that may happen. However, my question is, had there ever been a case where pilots broke this rule and chat in the crucial phases, and as a result caused an accident? After all, some pilots are extremely experienced, so they might've thought that they can chat while also performing their duties. Reality is, no matter how experienced a pilot can be, if they don't focus on their work, there's a large chance that there'll be a crash. So, had there ever been a crash caused by chatting in the cockpit in crucial phases of the flight? Or did every pilot adhered to the rules and focusing solely on their work when in the crucial stages? Or are some pilots actually experienced enough to fly the planes while doing other things? I appreciate any experience form pilots or any insights into this. Thanks in advance!

There have been incidents where things went off the rails where chit chat distractions were a major factor, usually on arrivals and approaches, although I can't think of specifics. In any case, the rule followed throughout the industry for many years is no small talk below 10,000 ft, coming or going. In western airline operations this is generally enforced. In dev world operations, maybe less so.

This may be trick to answer wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterile_flight_deck_rule appears to include a list of related incidents but would expect there to be few if any incidents where 'chatting' outright caused an incident, rather where it lead to something critical being missed

@AircraftEnthusiast007 I suspect this got some down votes for asking this question while simultaneously saying that 'there is a large chance there will be a crash' if pilots chat. This can be read that you are either asking this question in bad faith, or honestly believe pilots too dumb to talk and fly at the same time. From your other questions suspect that is not the case, but is how this question looks in isolation. Anytime you want an subject expert to answer, try to avoid anything that throws shade at that expert.

OK, thanks for the suggestion, so do I just delete that sentence? I certainly do not have any disrespect or distrust of pilots in anyway, and if my post shows this I apologize. Again, this is absolutely not what I mean and I would like to change that. So, do you suggest I just delete the sentence, or somehow reword it? If the latter, can you please give some advice on how to express what I actually mean while not sounding offensive? I appreciate your explanation and would like to hear your thoughts. Thanks :)

From the downvote tooltip: "This question does not show any research effort"

As for downvoting: I agree with @nobody since the answer to this question is readily availlable by simply googling and visiting the wikipedia article from the top of the search results. The reason for the "sterile cocpit rule" are the many accidents in which focus of the pilots was disturbed by chatting during critical phases of flight.

Air accidents rarely only have a single cause, but rather a list of contributing factors. Out of the top hundred accidents, distraction from conversation has been a contributing factor in some, but not the only one.
Chatter in the cockpit is more often a symptom of fatigue than the beginning of the accident chain of events. People intuitively try to stay awake and partially alert by engaging in conversation. It can also be a sign of complacency, which is more common in general aviation.
A major 2022 study has attempted to quantify the effect of various human factors on errors. Conversations are grouped under "Distraction from external factors". It was based on cabin crew rather than cockpit, but I haven't seen a study that specifically addresses pilot conversations.
Study on Factors That Influence Human Errors: Focused on Cabin Crew

The conclusion of the study did not support the hypothesis that conversations lead to a meaningfully higher human error rate. To clarify the numbers, β is the adjusted correlation coefficient, and p is the probability to see a positive correlation from random data. While science rarely closes the door on any hypothesis, a p-value above 0.5 means it's more likely wrong than right.
In other words, carrying out conversations does not, by itself, cause more errors, neither does time pressure. In contrast, fatigue, psychological stress and complacency definitely do.
Our brains have some capacity to filter out distractions and snap back to important tasks once alerted. This requires the higher-order cognitive system (also known as system 2), which gets severely degraded by fatigue or stress. There's also different grades of distraction, with a clicky pen or a fidget spinner on the lower end and a VR headset on the upper.
The Northwest 188 incident (thanks Aadiraj) was caused by distraction. However, it was much more severe than just conversations. Both pilots took off their headsets, took out their laptops, and worked the scheduling system together. This is much closer to VR than to idle chatter - the pilots were absorbed by a complex IT system, which required complete focus. The plane was a distraction, which their brains had successfully filtered out.
The sterile cockpit rule does allow for higher crew alertness and engagement, which help prevent other issues from developing into an accident. But other factors matter more.

Thanks a lot for your answer, it is very helpful. So chatting had never been the main reason of an accident. Your explanation is very clear and informative, so thanks for the great answer! Upvoted your post to show my gratitude :)

@AircraftEnthusiast007 I wouldn't say we know that, but if it was, we have no confirmation of that. For other factors, we have ample proof.

Northwest Airlines Flight 188 maybe?? Why not?

@AadirajAnil Maybe. However, the pilots' fault was far worse than idle chatter: they were both focused on another task, even working with a laptop. That's akin to doing a remote coding job.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 and others in this comment section: if not adhering to sterile cocpit rule was considered a factor, it shoud be seen as a partial reason for the accident. To put it otherwise: if the pilots had paid appropriate attention to their duties, they could have managed the other factors properly. So it is safe to say chatting has been a reason for many crashes.

There's grades of distraction, between small talk and escaping into a virtual reality. The Northwest case is much closer to the latter - the pilots were absorbed by a complex IT system that required complete focus. The plane was a distraction they successfully filtered out.

@Therac, by the time the captain figured out how to use the system, he didn't need it anymore.

@AadirajAnil Work-related distractions are the worst. At least, if you're playing video games at work, there's a trigger in the back of your mind to look out for the boss. Needless meetings look and feel like work, removing that alertness. So does working the company's scheduling system.

Not exactly conversation, but the infamous Eastern flight 401 that crashed while the crew was trying to change a light bulb on a landing gear indicator.  everyone was concentrating on how to change the bulb and no one was actually flying the plane. It was on autopilot, but someone, possibly the pilot, lean against the control wheel which disconnected the autopilot.  this was before the ground proximity warning systems which are now required due to this accident.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 Are you familiar with the swiss cheese model of accidents? The whole idea is that an accident almost never has a single cause. An incident usually is caused by a series of mistakes and failures that stack up in just the right way to avoid all the preventative measures. It's valid to say that distractions during a critical phase of flight have been major contributors to accidents in the past, but distraction alone almost never causes an incident; it's a distraction that lets a failure go unnoticed and grow from a simple "oops" to a life threatening situation.

@DarthPseudonym I agree that most accidents have multiple causes, but here I'm asking about something routine that was forgotten by pilots due to distractions. By "routine", I mean like they forgot to extend the landing gear, flaps, forgot to flare or rotate, or something similar. So I guess you can call what I want as having only one cause.

I don't think there's anything like that. There have been cases where an airliner accidentally landed with the the gear up, but not because Talk Too Much. Those routines are so routine that it would be hard to miss a step unless you have something going wrong that causes task saturation -- like, something disrupts the usual flow of the landing process, the pilot refuses to go around (get-there-itis) and in all the chaos a critical step gets skipped over. But that's not for chitty-chat reasons, it's usually like a plane-threatening situation came up at a bad moment.
